# Issue while fetching text out of HTML string

Tags: java

I have an HTML string: <myTag>Baby</myTag>.

I want the text "Baby" out of it in Java. Point here to note is that the tags could be lower case or upper case, for example:

<MYTAG>Baby</MyTag>.

Can someone please help me here?

Comment: Please share your code with us so we can help you improve/fix it

Comment: Any code you can share?

Comment: As a hack you could try `String result = str.substring(str.indexOf(">") + 1, str.indexOf("<"));` or simply upper case the string to get the start and end points

Comment: I don't have a code other than this problem statement. It should be a call to a replaceStr() method, where passing "<myTag>Baby</myTag>" or "<MYTAG>Baby</MyTag>" would produce the same result: "Baby". I tried one solution, but it didn't work since it is changing the actual text : inputText.toLowerCase().replace("<mytag>", "").replace("</mytag>", "");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String html = "<MYTAG>Baby</MyTag>";
        String content = "";

        boolean read = true;

        for(char c : html.toCharArray()) {

            if(c == '<' || c == '/') {
                read = false;
            }

            if(c == '>') {
                read = true;
            }

            if(read) {

                if(c != '>')
                    content += c;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(content);
    }

}
```

> Output : Baby

Comment: Thanks shekhar suman and Soumitri. Your solution works!!! But there could be scenarios like: <myOtherTag>Name<myTag>Baby</myTag></myOtherTag>. And I am only supposed to remove <myTag> & </myTag>.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar it it helped you then please vote it up and mark is as answer, Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following code :-

```
String given = "<MYTAG>Baby</MyTag>";
String required = given.substring(given.indexOf('>')+1,given.lastIndexOf('<');
```

Comment: @AbhishekKumar-For that, you simply need to perform -> 
`String required = given.substring(given.indexOf("<myTag>")+1,given.indexOf("</myTag>");`